# sed command not working with Java ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, bash, sed, processbuilder

I think this has to do with how I am splitting up the string array which I pass to Java's ProcessBuilder.

Here is the array I am passing to ProcessBuilder:

```
new String[]{"/bin/sh", "-c", 
     "ps -ef | grep Server | grep -v grep |", "sed", "-rn", "s/.*-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=([^ ]+).*/\\1/p"}
```

I am also escaping the '\' before the 1 at the end of my sed command.

This string always results in this error:

```
sed: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I've tried all sorts of different ways to quote the sed command, single quotes, double, none. Nothing seems to work. What am I missing here?

Comment: have you tried add single quotes around `"s/.*-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=([^ ]+).*/\\1/p"`?

Comment: Yes I have, single, double and no quotes

Comment: The entire pipeline needs to be a single string, as it is the argument for the `-c` option to `sh`. I don't remember Java well enough to know if the backslashes  in the `sed` command will need further escaping.

Comment: I know that the sed command needs to be separated out, so maybe I run my pipe line first and then pass that all back into a separate ProcessBuilder for sed. Although I don't really want to do that.